# Optimal $p$ for biased coin?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

You are given a biased coin with probability $p$ of getting $H$ and $1-p$ of getting tail. Each flip is independent of another. We keep flipping the coin until we get $4$ consecutive tails. For each tail, we get a $2$ dollars and for each head we lose $1$ dollar. What is the $p$ that would maximize the amount of money we have?

Comment: @AakashM Yes, $p>0$ delays the end of the game with the opportunity to win more (and hopefully not to lose too much).

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen the early history of probability theory should have warned me not to trust *intuition* about gambling :)

Comment: @AakashM You should especially never trust the *institution* (i.e. the bank holder) about gambling :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $E_k$ be the expected win if we start with a history of $k$ tails.
We want to maximize $E_0$.

We have
$$E_3 = p\cdot(-1+E_0) + (1-p)\cdot 2$$
as we either loose a dollar and start from $k=0$ again, or win two dollars and stop.
Similarly
$$E_2 = p\cdot(-1+E_0) + (1-p)\cdot (2+E_3)$$
$$E_1 = p\cdot(-1+E_0) + (1-p)\cdot (2+E_2)$$
$$E_0 = p\cdot(-1+E_0) + (1-p)\cdot (2+E_1).$$
Combining these equations, we find
$$E_0= \frac{3p^4-14p^3+26p^2-24p+8}{(p-1)^4}.$$
The derivative of this is
$$E_0'(p) =\frac{p^3-5p^2+10p-4}{(p-1)^5} $$
and has a single root in the interval $[0,1]$ at $p\approx 0.522$, which corresponds to a local maximum value of $\approx15.09$.